# Generating Static Pages - Understanding URL request

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge amount of content that is stored in a MySQL database, which powers my app. I would like to make this info available online to provide content for non-app users as well as increase my website ranking.

The backend of the app is run on PHP/MySQL. I therefore would like to use PHP to generate these pages (is this the correct method?). I guess the PHP would take the structure of the url, for instance `www.xxxx.com/viewer/**venue**/**id**` where the parts in ** ** are variable. How do I get PHP to route the request based on these?

Comment: URL Rewriting; [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best and most efficient method is to use URL rewriting within Apache. Add the following code to your `.htaccess` file (or create one if it doesn't exist) in your root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/viewer/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ viewer.php?venue=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Now, create a `viewer.php` file inside your root. You can then access the variables as part of the `$_GET` super-global as follows:

```
$venue = $_GET['venue'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Please be advised that you should SQL injection in your code, and sanitize these inputs accordingly.

Comment: Great! If I apply the Apache mod to my current server will it still serve old pages correctly (ie my old index.php etc), or will all requests go through viewer.php now?

Comment: No, the RewriteRule only targets any URL that matches your pattern (i.e. `/viewer/()/()`).

Comment: One last question, does this make the page crawlable by search engines?

Comment: Yes, but you should use canonical URL tags to ensure Google picks up the correct version.

Comment: Just to add to this for future, I had to add a slash before viewer.php to get this to work on EC2/EB

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your web server.

If you're using PHP5-FPM with Nginx:

```
location /viewer {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/viewer.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Would probably do it.  Then in PHP, you would need to explode your $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] path after /viewer and run your logic based on that.

Example:

```
<?
$parts = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$i=0;
while($parts[$i] != 'viewer'){
  unset($parts[$i]);
  $i++;
}
if($parts[$i] == 'viewer') unset($parts[$i]);
$parts = array_values($parts);
var_dump($parts);
?>
```

You should see an array of all the values after your /viewer/ (venue and ID).